# Opening a JDialog on the click of a button

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I am trying to open a `JDialog` when a button in a `JFrame` is pressed and that dialog should contain a `JTable`.

Where should I create the dialog (inside the frame or should a new class be created)?

Comment: *"Where should i create the Jdialogue(inside the Jframe or a new class should be created)"* Either. Whichever works best for the design of the app. Voted to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: I tried creating a jdialogue using the create jdialogue wizard but it's source contains the main function and the main jframe also has a main function

Comment: Tip: Add @daniu (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: *"but it's source contains the main function and the main jframe also has a main function"* which is irrelevant - you can remove the `main` from the `dialog` class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your dialog is rather complex use a new class for it. 
Do something like

```
public class OtherDialog extends JDialog {
  // ...
  public OtherDialog(){
    // build dialog
  } 
}
```

and open it in your JFrame-Button-Actionhandler  like this:

```
protected void btnOpenotherdialogActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        OtherDialog dialog = new OtherDialog();
        dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```